# How to Select Files in Android Application with 'drive.file' Scope

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am currently working on the development of a full native Android application and have received communication from Google to transition from the restricted 'auth/drive' scope to the less restrictive 'auth/drive.file' scope.

During this migration, I have two questions:

1. How can users access files or folders with the 'drive.file' scope in a full native Android app, excluding the use of the Google Picker API?
   I encountered a '404 File not found' error while trying to retrieve a folder in my development environment. Is there a workaround for this issue without changing the scope?
2. If the first method is not feasible, how can the Google Picker API be used on Android?
   The documentation indicates that, for Android, the use of the Google Workspace API is the only option. In this case, is it possible to achieve functionality similar to selecting Google Drive files using the Google Picker API through methods other than the Google Workspace API?
   [Link to Google Picker API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/picker)

I've been working on transitioning from the 'auth/drive' scope to the less restrictive 'drive.file' scope in a native Android application. Here are the steps I've taken and the issue I'm facing:

1. Obtained a refresh token with the 'drive.file' scope by making changes in the authorization process and acquiring an access token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.
2. Sent a request to retrieve the list of folders using GET /drive/v3/files, but the response's 'items' field is empty.
3. Attempted to access the root folder by sending a request with GET /drive/v3/files/{fileId}, specifying the fileId of the root folder. However, a '404 File not found' error was returned, indicating that access to the folder is not possible.

I followed the official documentation for the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3)

Code for sending a request for GET /drive/v3/files/{fileId}:

```
// Header
Header[] requestHeaders = new Header[]{
        // Access token already obtained from post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
        new BasicHeader("Authorization", accessToken),
        new BasicHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"),
        new BasicHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"),
        new BasicHeader("Accept", "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2"),
        new BasicHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
};

InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    // Perform a GET request to retrieve data
    setHttpResponse(
            doGet(httpClient, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}", requestHeaders)
    );
    int status = getHttpResponse().getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    // setting response data
    inputStream = getHttpResponse().getEntity().getContent();
    String responseContentType = GoogleDriveUtils.getResponseContentType(this.getHttpResponse());

    // Error determination
    // Status other than 200 or Content-Type other than "application/json"
    if (status != 200 || !GoogleDriveUtils.isContentTypeJson(responseContentType)) {
        // exception 
        throw GoogleDriveUtils.createGoogleDriveException(
                fulUrl, inputStream, status, responseContentType,
                this.getHttpResponse(), GoogleDriveConsts.PROCESS_TYPE_RETRIEVAL);
    }

    // Response Analysis
    googleDriveAboutInfo = GoogleDriveAboutInfo.parseGoogleDriveAboutInfo(inputStream);

}
```

Here is the error message received:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: {FileID}",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "File not found: {FileID}",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "location": "file",
        "locationType": "other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo  
The investigation details were incorrect. I have corrected the content of the text.  

The error encountered when sending a request to /drive/v2/files/{fileId} was not '403 PERMISSION_DENIED' as previously mentioned. Instead, the correct error received was '404 File not found' in the response.
I have confirmed that OAuth 2.0 authentication is successful.

Is it the expected behavior that, when using the 'drive.file' scope, sending a request to /drive/v2/files/{fileId} with the fileId of the root folder results in a '404 File not found' error?

Comment: why are you using drive v2.  please include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo
We were verifying with drive v2 because we were using drive v2 in our existing code.
We also verified with v3 with similar results.
We also described the code that sent the request.

Comment: Same issue here. The `drive.file` scope only allows access to files created by your app or files that a user shared with your app by using the Google Picker API. Unfortunately Google Picker API is only for web apps and I haven't found anything similar for mobile apps (but it may be possible to use it in a WebView). Please note that you can still use restricted scopes but it will require a so called Cloud Application Security Assessment